# Как правильно менять виджеты главного окна ( QMainWindow ) Qt

Tags: qt

Требуется реализовать несколько виджетов из главного окна QMainWindow, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку эти удалялись или скрывались, а показывались другие, и наоборот

> Как показывать/не показывать виджеты? Может есть какая то функция или свойство?

Реализовывала 2 класса виджетов в конструкторе вызывала сначала 1 класс(первая картинка) там же писала соединение со вторым классом, из 2 (картинки) класса в 1 класс попасть нельзя

Прошу прощения за Paint

[image: Второе положение виджетов]
[image: Первое положение виджетов]

Comment: Сигналы/слоты использовать умеете?

Comment: @V-Mor да, я перехожу по сигналу/слоту что нужно сделать с виджетом? как спрятать?

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет, у каждого виджета есть метод `Hide()` или что-то похожее с этим словом

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут есть два варианта, первый это скрывать каждый виджет по отдельности, с помощью:
setHidden();

Пример:

```
ui->pushButton->setHidden(true);
ui->pushButton_2->setHidden(true);

// и показывать другие:
ui->pushButton_3->setHidden(false);
ui->pushButton_4->setHidden(false);
```

второй же, это использовать QStackedWidget создать страницы, и в каждой странице расположить по несколько виджетов, и менять индекс QStackedWidget:

Пример:

```
ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
// или 1 и так далее в зависимости какая страница нужна
```

Ссылка на документацию по QStackedWidget https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html